# Search for a specific message in Active MQ queue

Tags: java, xpath, activemq-classic

I have an ActiveMQ instance, with a couple of topics and queues. Sometimes, it would be nice to search in a queue, for a specific message, matching a certain string.

Is that possible? I tried using XPath, but I'm tired of get this exception:

javax.jms.InvalidSelectorException

I'm accessing the ActiveMQ queue using the web console url: /hawtio/#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after a lot of investigation, I found this command:

```
./activemq browse --amqurl tcp://localhost:61616 <QUEUE>
```

This will list all the messsages in , and then you can do a grep over the result and search for whatever you want.